# Why is Wireshark not capturing certain POST requests?

Tags: java, wireshark

If I use this filter in Wireshark: `http.request.method == "POST"` and use the vote buttons to vote for a stack exchange question, then Wireshark captures the corresponding POST request. I can also see in Chromes debugger that the request is a POST.

However, on another site that I'm trying to examine, when I click on a form button that triggers a POST (and Chromes debugger confirms that it is a POST) then Wireshark captures nothing.

Why might this be?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all the tips. Utimately, I did get to examine a POST sent from my webserver using Fiddler, and it did help me out. I didn't mention it, but my webserver is Jetty running locally on Ubuntu, and I'm using Apache HttpClient for handling requests. For Java, if your not using HttpClient, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549749/how-to-capture-https-with-fiddler-in-java) is helpful. If you are, then check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0) out.

In either case, Fiddler still needs to be setup to monitor HTTPS connections by checking the option at Tools --> Fiddler Options --> HTTPS --> Capture HTTPS CONNECTs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTPS encrypts the contents of the message from anyone snooping on the wire - which is exactly what you are doing - so it's working as intended.  Anyone doing packet captures anywhere between the browser and webserver just see encrypted traffic.

Wireshark isn't the best tool for analysing HTTPS traffic.  For that, you can use the debugger built into the browser, or something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), which runs as a proxy server on your machine and decrypts HTTPS traffic.

Fiddler does this by sitting in the middle - the webserver is having an HTTPS conversation with Fiddler, and your browser is having an HTTPS conversation with Fiddler.  But Fiddler is able to decrypt both connections.  This will of course throw up scary invalid certificate warnings unless you add Fiddler's CA certificate to your browser/OS.

Wireshark WILL work if you have the SSL private key file.  So if you are on the webserver end of things, [load your SSL private key into Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) and it will decrypt the traffic for you.  This only works if you have access to the private key - you won't be able to decrypt traffic to/from stackexchange this way, but you can use it for web servers you control.

Now that you've clarified the traffic is from your webserver to a third party, I have another option for you, if you are on Linux or Mac: [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/index.html)

Either fiddler or mitmproxy should be able to do the man in the middle decryption for you.  The tricky part is getting the data to pass through the proxy.  On linux this is relatively easy using iptables - the mitmproxy gives setup instructions for that.  On both windows and linux you should be able to use [Apache's mod_proxy ProxyRemote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493574/configure-apache-web-server-to-use-a-proxy-server) settings to direct traffic to your proxy server.

Comment: Is it possible to configure Fiddler to intercept requests sent from a webserver running on my machine, or does it only work with requests from browsers?

Comment: @RTF added advice if you are on the webserver side of things.

Comment: The request that I want to debug is actually being sent from a webserver that I do own to a HTTPS server that I don't own. Does that mean that the traffic is encrypted using the destination servers public key, and since I don't have their private key, I can't use Wireshark?

Comment: @RTF more options added.

Comment: The symmetric encryption keys that are negotiated during connection opening are based on the HTTPS server's private key. So, in order to decrypt the communication, you need the destination server's private key.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen exactly.  If you don't have that, you use a MitM proxy - so the connection goes "Your server" -https-> "Proxy" -different_https-> "Their server".  The proxy is the one who is really talking to the remote server, so it can see the unencrypted data.

Comment: And with the proxy approach, one should disable certificate checking in the client that makes the HTTPS connection to the server, otherwise the connection won't work at all.

Comment: @terokilkanen that or add the ca cert your proxy is signing the fake certs with to your trusted ca list.

Comment: Fiddler can capture traffic from webservers running on your machine, as long as you can convince the server to trust the Fiddler root certificate.  If the server uses the Windows certificate store *(I imagine most do)*, you can do that right from Fiddler.  Also, if the server uses the WinHTTP stack *(instead of the usual WinINET)*, you'll need to do [some additional configuration](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-04-29/using-fiddler-with-winhttp)

Comment: @RTF you want to run [Fiddler as a reverse proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/usefiddlerasreverseproxy)

Answer (score 3):

It *might* be because the other side is using `HTTPS`.

Comment: It is using HTTPS, I just realized that. It seems I can't analyse the POST request then because I don't own the HTTPS server